# Get geolocation coordinates [ latitude, longitude ] of current location in NextJS/ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, next.js, geolocation, userlocation

I need the `latitude`, `longitude` of the **current location** of the user to show posts accordingly, I'm using next.js can anyone help me out?

Comment: Are you asking for current path ?

Comment: current address location

Comment: What do you mean by that? Can you show us some code to better explain what you're trying to achieve?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I solve it by doing following :-

```
useEffect(()=> {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
      console.log("Latitude is :", position.coords.latitude);
      console.log("Longitude is :", position.coords.longitude);
    });
  })
```

Comment: Worked fine! Thanks mate.

Answer (score -3):

use `router.pathName` - This provides the current path -

```
import { useRouter } from 'next/router'

const router = useRouter();

const currentPath = router.pathName

//...rest of your code
```

This ensures availability both via SSR and CSR

Ref: https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/router

Comment: Please read the question before answering. Totally different thing you are answering about.